# How do i create a web service from on Demand Service?

Tags: java, web-services

I am a novice in programming. Currently we have a service that will be triggered only with the click of a button that generates a Id. but my team wants to create a webservice to run it as a webservice. How do i create a shadow service from the same one.

Don't know how to do it.